# Color whole section line in org-mode depending on tag

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The question says it all. I would like to change the background color of all sections labeled with a particular tag (e.g. :WORK:) in my org-mode file. I found out how to change the colors of the TODO states, but I wasn't successful in changing the color of the whole line. Can that be done? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: fabee, how did you "change the colors of the TODO states?" I would like to do that myself but don't know how. I'm assuming you mean changing the colors of the todo states based on the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use font-lock-add-keywords:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
 '(("^.*:write:.*$" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

See `C-h f font-lock-add-keywords` RET for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such code that's ready to copy or use, AFAICT. Though, I'm sure it can be done, but will require hand-made code.

However, if you'd be interested to have such highlighting in the agenda buffer, you should check out some post of John Wiegley, a couple of years ago.

Comment: Thanks. I wait a little before accepting your answer (because of the AFAICT part).